# お名前ドットコムでお名前メールを使用している場合の DNS の設定方法

Tags: heroku, dns

DNS 周りで、お名前ドットコム - Heroku - お名前メール の3つの紐付けに関して分からない部分があります。

お名前ドットコムで取得した独自ドメインを Heroku で公開するにあたり、先日 DNS の設定を行いました。画像①はお名前ドットコム側で CNAME の紐づけを行ったものです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これにより、 CNAME の状態を確認すると primary name server が画像①にも表示されている `01.dnsv.jp` になりました。

```
C:\Users\app\hogeapp>nslookup -type=CNAME hogeapp.com 
サーバー:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.38.203

hogeapp.com 
        primary name server = 01.dnsv.jp
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.dnsv.jp
        serial  = 1642765227
        refresh = 3600 (1 hour)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 300 (5 mins)
```

これで独自ドメインでアプリを Heroku で無事公開する事が出来るようになりました。
ですが、この設定をする前に、実はお名前ドットコムで「お名前メール」サービスも利用しておりました。そして利用していた際のネームサーバーは以下の物（画像②）です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

今回自身で DNS レコード設定を行った為、お名前メールで使用していた `dns01.gmoserver.jp` から、 DNS レコードをカスタムした際の `01.dnsv.jp` に変更したと言う事になります。
これによりメール機能の一部が使えなくなってしまいました（具体的にはお名前メールがメールの受信をしてくれません）。

そこで [Qiita 記事](https://qiita.com/tomomomo1217/items/47195a7025d9f92302e8)を参考に、お名前メールのサーバーのDNS設定も試みました（画像③）。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかしこれでもメール機能がまだ使えません。
よく見てみると、お名前メールのサーバーのDNS設定で「TTL値は600になります」と断りがありました。先日お名前.comの（メールとは別の）DNS関連機能設定にて 3600 で設定した部分があるのですが（画像①にある値です）、これらは勝手に変えて良い物なのでしょうか？
どなたかご助言を頂けますと有難いです。

Comment: 当該サービスは、私の認識するところではレジストラとしてあるまじき「外部DNSサーバーの利用を公式に認めていない」サービスであり、今回のような外部はおろか自社サービスすらも同様です。[こちらのブログ](https://blog.ryou103.com/post/onamae-nameserver/)にて示されているように必要なMX，TXTレコードがわかれば設定は可能なはずですが。（シンプルな質問への答え: MX,TXTレコードを設定する必要があります）

Comment: 有難うございます！また対応が遅くなりまして申し訳ありません。

頂いたリンク先に説明があります「レンタルサーバー SDプラン、お名前メールのネームサーバーを使う」を選択し確認、と言う所までやったのですが、https://www.whatsmydns.net/ で何日経っても NS が浸透しません。CNAME は浸透しているのですが…。
質問文に記載しております「画像③」などの他の設定は、質問文の状態のままです。他の部分も変えないと NS は反映されないのでしょうか？
可能でしたら再度ご助言頂けますと有難いです。

Comment: お陰様で、MX、TXTレコードを追加する事で無事メールを受信する事が出来ました！有難うございました。
ベストアンサーにさせて頂きたいので、可能であれば同じ文章で構いませんのでご回答頂けませんでしょうか。

また、上記の「NS が浸透しなかった」原因ですが、確認するドメイン名に余計な「www.」を付けていたからでした。CNAME が反映されていたのも当然です。
「www.」を取り除いた正式なドメイン名で確認すると既に NS も反映されておりました。